# How can I have one col-4 column with a max-width and other col-8 column fill in the remainder?

Tags: bootstrap-4

```
class row/container
  class col-lg-4 max-width: 600px;
  class col-lg-8 100%;
```

The problem is that it seems like that max-width establishes the column size (150px in this case) and therefor limits the size of the second column to 8x150.

I want the 2nd col to fill in the rest of the width - but it doesnt. Everything works fine up until the first col hits 600 and then the 2nd col wont get any bigger. The parent row is full width, however with the empty space on the right.

While this would be easy outside of BS, I am trying to avoid breaking the BS functionality here.

Comment: Just add `min-width: 66.666666667%; width: calc(100% - 400px);`.

Comment: Thanks, but I added min-width: 66.666666667%; width: calc(100% - 600px) to the 2nd col and its still limited by the 1st col max-width. Removing the max width from the 1st col results in a standard 33.3/66.6 BS split.

Comment: I stumbled upon the answer accidentally. The second col needs to be just "col" - no breakpoint or column count.